# How do you return inside a promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm beginning to teach myself javascript and am having trouble returning from a function inside a promise. My code, essentially, looks like this:

```
foobar = function(x,y){
    //code that doesn't matter
    return promiseFunction(
        function(results){
           console.log("promise completed")
           console.log(output)
           return output;}
        function(err){throw error;});

console.log(foobar('1','2'));
```

This prints

```
undefined
promise completed
what I want the result to be
```

I'm new to asynchronous programming and am not certain what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asynchronous functions don't return (or at least, not reliably). By the time you get a value from your asynchronous function, `console.log` has already run with what it has (in this case, nothing, or `undefined`). This is a lesson I learned hard and fast when I started out with it. If you want something to happen after an asynchronous function, you have to call it inside of the asynchronous function.

See the thread [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) for more info and suggestions.

Comment: So foobar('1','2') is returning output, but console.log is printing 'undefined' before foobar('1','2') has a chance to return?

Comment: @user1231120 - Bingo!

Answer (score 7):

You don't `return` inside a promise. You chain another task after its completion - getting back a new promise for the completion of the chained task:

```
function foobar(x,y){
    // Assuming that promiseFunction does return a promise
    return promiseFunction().then(function(results){
         console.log("promise completed")
         console.log(output)
         return output;
    }, function(err) {
         throw error;
    });
}
foobar('1','2').then(function(output) {
    console.log(output);
})
```

If `promiseFunction` does not return a promise yet, check [this section of the `Q` documentation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/#the-beginning) about how to construct promises for a few examples and patterns.

Comment: If I call foobar('1','2').then... I get "TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined". This presumably means foobar('1','2') does not return a promise? Looking around it looks like wrapping promiseFunction()... in a $.ajax() should fix that. How do I add jquery to just a javascript file? There is no HTML file.

Comment: Well, the function I posted *does* `return` a promise. Does `promiseFunction` return the result of `$.ajax`? If you don't already use jQuery, you should better use a different library. How are you executing the script without HTML? There's probably some kind of `import` or `require` in such an environment.