# Show verification menu only if user is not verified in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I want to display **User Verification** menu only if user is not verified in node js

```
header.ejs
<% if(!isVerified(user.id)){%>
    <li><a href="/auth/logout">User Verification</a></li>
<% } %>
```

function.js

```
module.exports.isVerified = function(user_id) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id='+mysql.escape(user_id)+' and verified=1';
    config.db.query(sql,function (err, rows){
      if(err){
        reject(false);
      }else{
        resolve(rows);
      }
    });  
  });
}
```

but it is not showing the menu....what should i do? I don't know i'm new in nodejs. Thanks in advance

Comment: Firstly, Are you able to fetch the `rows` ?

Comment: yes i'm getting the row

Comment: does your `config.db.query` returns promise or it is promise function?

Comment: no...`config.db` is simple mysql pool like this `db : mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100, //important
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'abc',
    debug    :  false
}),`  and query is simple function of that pool

Comment: could you point me to the documentation of this mysql module? I suspect it should return promise

Comment: (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#performing-queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after a week i have solved this problem

function.js (same as i have posted in question)

```
module.exports.isVerified = function(user_id) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id='+mysql.escape(user_id)+' and verified=1';
    config.db.query(sql,function (err, rows){
      if(err){
        reject(false);
      }else{
        resolve(rows);
      }
    });  
  });
}
```

now the change that i have done here is in `app.js` and `header.ejs` file.

app.js

```
const fn = require('./helper/function_helper')
app.use(async function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.session.user.id){
    res.locals.user = await fn.isVerified (req.session.user.id);
    //so now i can access user.verified in header.ejs file.
  }
  next();
});
```

header.ejs

```
//instead of using the isVerified() function I have used the user.verified
<%if(user.verified==0){%>
     <li><a href="/home/user-verification">User Verification</a></li>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your promise doesn't return a boolean, it wait and indicate if the SQL query worked or not, you  need to return a boolean in both case.

Comment: i have changed the code like this `if(rows.length>0){
          resolve(true);
        }else{
          resolve(false);
        }` still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a promise, you are dealing with asynchronous programming. What that means is that, your returns are unpredictable. How you should fix that is defining promise separately and check it with a code block similar to `.then(function(res){...})`

I recommend you to look at these resources:

1. [Javascript Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises)
2. [How to return inside promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232280/how-do-you-return-inside-a-promise)

Comment: so is there any way to do this without promise?...please Help me if you know

Answer (score 0):

use a module for node that provide synchronous functions. Here you'll find a module that provide sync/async functions to deal with mysql:
 [node-mysql-libmysqlclient](https://github.com/Will-I4M/node-mysql-libmysqlclient)

```
    //Sample code
    module.exports.isVerified = function (user_id) {

    var config = require("./config.json") ;
    var mysql = require('mysql-libmysqlclient') ;
    var client = mysql.createConnectionSync(config.host, config.user, config.password, config.database) ;
    var flag = false;
    var query = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id=' + mysql.escape(user_id) + ' and verified=1' ;
    var handle = client.querySync(query) ;
    var results = handle.fetchAllSync() ;
    if (results.length > 0)
    {
        flag = true;
    } else
    {
        flag = false;
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results)) ;
    return flag;

}
```

Comment: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: config.db.query(...).then is not a function` i'm getting this error now

Comment: right, In that case  would suggest using different library. Have a look at this. If this fine I will update the code
https://github.com/Will-I4M/node-mysql-libmysqlclient

Also why you need promise block in that case, could you not just have function without promise block?

Comment: can i do this without promise and then,catch block?

Comment: Not sure, you need to give a try. Updated solution

Comment: Do you want to try with different library?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this fix your problem, but your ejs code is wrong. You have not closed the ejs tags. This is the proper syntax

```
<% if(!isVerified(user.id)){ %>
    <li><a href="/auth/logout">User Verification</a></li>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I think problem is in isVerified function..can you please help me...

Comment: ejs is a rendered template language. How do you send `isVerified` to the ejs file?

Comment: by using `app.locals` like this `app.locals = require('./helper/function')`